# ZF2 : disable error page layout

Tags: model-view-controller, exception, zend-framework2, zend-view

im trying to disable layout while showing error/exception page in my zf2 module

but nothing works

please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Final Solution in my Module.php

```
$eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();



        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, function($e) {
             $result = $e->getResult();
             $result->setTerminal(TRUE);

            });
```

it works and only loads error/404 view file  not the layout file

thanks andrew

Comment: The dispatch.error event is never triggered in my case (I'm using the zf2 skeleton from github), though a 404 error is shown. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the Zend Framework 2 MVC module you will see possibilities for this..

DispatchListener.php

```
    try {
        $return = $controller->dispatch($request, $response);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $e->setError($application::ERROR_EXCEPTION)
              ->setController($controllerName)
              ->setControllerClass(get_class($controller))
              ->setParam('exception', $ex);
        // look here...
        $results = $events->trigger(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, $e);
        $return = $results->last();
        if (! $return) {
            $return = $e->getResult();
        }
    }
```

You can see they MvcEvent which is triggered when you have an exception thrown inside the controller, there's a few other processes attaching to this event.

You could attach a method to this event and do what ever you want.

As an example look at ExceptionStrategy.php

```
public function prepareExceptionViewModel(MvcEvent $e)
{
     ....
}
```

Comment: so if i override EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR in my module.php bootstrap function and disable the layout there will works?   how to disable the layout

Answer (score 0):

this is not your ans but it will help to other 
in zf2

```
 public function indexAction()
    {    
        echo "json"
        return $this->getResponse();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use config `config/autoload/local.php`

```
return array(
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_exceptions' => false
    )
);
```

Adding this lines disables exceptions. In addition you can use your own `local.php` on a dev server.