# ZF2: Changing Layout on Exception

Tags: layout, exception, zend-framework2, zend-view

Whenever there is an exception in my ZF2 application I want to display it in a custom layout.  (The custom layout is very vanilla, i.e. does not use any application variables).

I am happy with the default view templates, i.e. error/404 and error/index, but I want them to render with a different layout.

Here's my setup:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'layout'                   => 'layout/secure',
    .....
```

At the moment, all exceptions are rendered with the 'layout/secure' layout, which uses some application variables (such as user name).  When 'layout/secure' cannot render (because a user is not logged in, for example), it throws a second error.

I tried overriding the layout on dispatch.error and render.error, per the following code, but it still tries to render the secure layout.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, function(MvcEvent $event) {
        $viewModel = $event->getViewModel();
        $viewModel->setTemplate('layout/vanilla');
    });

    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER_ERROR, function(MvcEvent $event) {
        $viewModel = $event->getViewModel();
        $viewModel->setTemplate('layout/vanilla');
    });
}
```

I tried registering these with low (negative) priority, and high positive priority, but it made no difference.

Comment: Did you try adding your 'error/index' path to your `template_map`? Configuration points to it as `exception_template`.

Comment: Yes, edigu, I did.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14760681/1908296